# How do I keep squirrels and raccoons from getting in my garage soffits and filling it with leaves etc until the soffit pieces fall out

Tags: roof

How do I keep the squirrels and raccoons from filling my garage soffits with leaves etc until the soffit pieces fall out.
I had the soffits replaced two years ago because of this and they are back at it. I have to figure out how to put three soffit pieces up. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Are these animals pulling away soffit vents or sections of the soffit itself?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! If you would [edit] some pictures in showing what your soffits look like and, possibly a damaged one where the critters have gotten in, that would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, without knowing how they're getting in we can't help much. I live in Squirrel and Chipmunk Central and don't have this problem. Racoons?? Never heard of that.